# Как получить значение числа ПИ во время компиляции?

Tags: c++

Как получить значение числа ПИ с заданной точностью во время компиляции?

Comment: Взять число с заведомо лишними цифрами после запятой, и ограничиваться нужными. А вообще - **зачем** это нужно, поясните. Может, ваша сверхзадача решается иначе...

Comment: @Harry нужно получить значение числа ПИ с заданной точностью во время компиляции

Comment: Вы же просто вопрос повторили, ну. :/ А мы спрашиваем, для чего вам это нужно.

Comment: Вам хватит той точности, которая помещается в `long double`, или может потребоваться произвольно большая точность?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat хватит

Comment: @3.14 Такое ощущение, что вы прикалываетесь... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В основном взято [отсюда](https://timmurphy.org/2013/06/27/template-metaprogramming-in-c/)  Добавлено только ограничение точности.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

// Generic exponent compile-time calculations. Pow<2,3>::result == 2^3
template <unsigned long B, unsigned long E>
struct Pow
{
    static constexpr double result = B * Pow<B, E - 1>::result;
};

template <unsigned long B>
struct Pow<B, 0>
{
    static constexpr double result = 1;
};

// Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe formula for calculating pi
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe_formula
template <unsigned long N>
struct CalculatePi
{
    static constexpr double pi =
        (
            1.0 / Pow<16, N>::result *
            (
                4.0 / (8 * N + 1.0) - 2.0 / (8 * N + 4.0) -
                1.0 / (8 * N + 5.0) - 1.0 / (8 * N + 6.0)
                )
            ) + CalculatePi<N - 1>::pi;
        ;
};

template <>
struct CalculatePi<-1>
{
    static constexpr double pi = 0.0;
};

template <int IT = 10, int N = 10>
struct Pecision : public CalculatePi<IT>
{
    static constexpr double value =  (long long)(CalculatePi<IT>::pi * Pow <10, N>::result) / Pow <10, N>::result;
};

template <>
struct Pecision<0>
{
    static constexpr double value = 0.0;
};

// main program. Print pi, calculated from 10 iterations of
// the BBP formula above
int main()
{
    std::cout.precision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10);
    std::cout << "pi: " << Pecision <10>::value << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Меняю значение в Precision, но количество знаков не изменяется

Comment: @3.14 Набросал на скорую руку, надо было точность первым параметром поставить. поэтому надо писать так  Pecision <10, 9> второй параметр точность

Comment: При 10,19 уже не работает

Comment: Но тут больше знаков чем в другом ответе

Comment: @3.14 Для double вот так будет более корректно Pecision<10, std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10>::value

Answer (score 2):

Например с помощью серий Грэгори.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
T calculatePi(int depth)
{
    T pi = 0;
    bool sign = true; // true: +, false: -
    for (int i = 1; i < depth; i += 2)
    {

        if (sign)
            pi += 1/static_cast<T>(i);
        else
            pi -= 1/static_cast<T>(i);
        sign = !sign;    

    }
    return pi*4;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << calculatePi<double>(10000);
}
```

Comment: Так это же не во время компиляции

Comment: @3.14 Поставьте перед функцией `constexpr` - будет во время компиляции.

Comment: Проблема в том что в теле constexpr функции может быть только return

Comment: @ishidex2 Это же только в С++11, вроде. У меня этот код компилируется с C++14 и выше.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat поставил - всё равно в рантайме считает

Comment: К тому же тут задаётся количество итераций, а не точность

Comment: @3.14 (1) Либо оптимизацию включите, либо напишите `constepxr double x = calculatePi<double>(10000);` - тогда будет во время компиляции. (2) Так ведь поменять условие несложно. Если разница между текущим и предыдущим значениями меньше точности - заканчиваете цикл.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat написал через переменную - теперь работает, но не совсем). Чтобы тут получить хотя бы 6 знаков, нужно много итераций и поэтому появляется ошибка компиляции при 1000000 итераций например error: ‘constexpr’ loop iteration count exceeds limit of 262144

Comment: @HolyBlackCat но даже если я расширю с помощью настроек компилятора это значение, всё равно до максимальной точности double как до луны :(

Comment: @3.14 Еще раз, может вы скажете, зачем вам это? Для реального кода, или это лабораторная/курсовая? Если первое, то взяли бы готовую константу.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat просто интересно, руками готовое значение любой может написать :)

Comment: Как по мне это бессмыслица.

Comment: @3.14 А почему вы компилятор готовый используете, так ведь любой может. Нужно свой. :Р

Comment: @HolyBlackCat как по мне интересное задание по С++, учитывая что готовых констант в библиотеке нет. Компилятор более сложное задание написать, да и тут никто это не будет делать. Если вам не интересно, я не заставляю отвечать

Comment: Это я так, в шутку. Если по делу, советую просто поискать более быстрые алгоритмы вычисления пи. Необходимость вычислять во время компиляции никаких ограничений на алгоритм не накладывает, разве что на число итераций, как вы сами увидели.

Comment: @3.14 а как же константа M_PI из cmath?